# How to randomly pull same index from two arrays?

Tags: php, function, variables, random

My function is outputting what it should. When I run this, all I get is "It was then that the gods reached out and decided to give the power of to aid in this quest." How can I make it pick the same index from both arrays and fill in the variables in the echo?

```
function gift_giver()
{
    $people = array ("$heroname", "$friendname", "$wizardname", "Captain Rumbeard", "$frogname");
    $gifts = array("a magic compass", "the gift of no fear", "all seeing powers", "more rum", "a delightful lilly pad");
    $gift_selector=(rand(0,4));
    $gift_recipient=$people[$gift_selector];
    $gift_present=$gift[$gift_selector];
    echo "It was then that the gods reached out and decided to give $gift_recipient the power of $gift_present to aid in this quest.<br/><br/>";
}
```

Comment: For one, it should be `$gifts`, not `$gift`.

Comment: I fixed this in an edit; waiting for approval....

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton You shouldn't fix bugs in an edit.

Comment: Where is `$heroname` defined? Outside of your function?

Answer (score 1):

Bugs and undefined variables aside, your function might benefit from some refactoring:

```
function gift_giver(array $people, array $gifts)
{
    // take entry that will not overshoot either array
    $entry = rand(0, min(count($people), count($gifts)) - 1);

    printf(
        'It was then that the gods reached out and decided to give %s the power of %s to aid in this quest.<br/><br/>',
        $people[$entry],
        $gifts[$entry]
    );
}

gift_giver(['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'boo']);
// It was then that the gods reached out and decided to give bar the power of baz 
// to aid in this quest.<br/><br/>
```

This way your function is solely responsible for generating text with inputs from both arrays. Tailored for your specific case:

```
gift_giver(
    array($heroname, $friendname, $wizardname, "Captain Rumbeard", $frogname),
    array("a magic compass", "the gift of no fear", "all seeing powers", "more rum", "a delightful lilly pad")
);
```

**Update**

Seeing how both arrays are related, you may also consider mapping them into a single array:

```
function gift_giver(array $people_gift_map)
{
    $key = array_rand($people_gift_map);
    printf(
        'It was then that the gods reached out and decided to give %s the power of %s to aid in this quest.<br/><br/>',
        $key,
        $people_gift_map[$key]
    );
}

gift_giver(array(
    $heroname => "a magic compass", 
    $friendname => "the gift of no fear", 
    $wizardname => "all seeing powers", 
    "Captain Rumbeard" => "more rum", 
    $frogname => "a delightful lilly pad",
));
```

Comment: OP wants the same array index for gift/person not both random.

Comment: @Class That's true, but in that case OP might as well use a single array, mapping each person => gift :)

Comment: @Jack that would make things simpler for OP.

Answer (score 0):

In your `$people` array, everything beginning with a `$` is being treated as a variable because you're surrounding the strings with double quotes (`"`). Try this:

```
function gift_giver($heroname, $friendname, $wizardname, $frogname) {
    $people = array($heroname, $friendname, $wizardname, "Captain Rumbeard", $frogname);
    $gifts = array("a magic compass", "the gift of no fear", "all seeing powers", "more rum", "a delightful lilly pad");

    $gift_selector = rand(0,4);
    $gift_recipient = $people[$gift_selector];
    $gift_present = $gifts[$gift_selector];

    echo "It was then that the gods reached out and decided to give $gift_recipient the power of $gift_present to aid in this quest.<br/><br/>";
}
```

Comment: Alrighty, well they're set by the user as this is meant to tell a sort of Mad Libs type story. Any idea how I can get around that?

Comment: I did it with the single quotes and got "...decided to give $friendname the power of to aid in this quest."

Comment: It would do as PHP is now treating them as literal strings. I've now switched them to arguments - probably what you initially intended :)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a s in `$gift[$gift_selector]`

```
function gift_giver($heroname, $friendname, $wizardname, $frogname){
    #or define $heroname $friendname $wizardname $frogname here
    $people = array($heroname, $friendname, $wizardname, "Captain Rumbeard", $frogname);
    $gifts = array("a magic compass", "the gift of no fear", "all seeing powers", "more rum", "a delightful lilly pad");
    $gift_selector = (rand(0,4));
    $gift_recipient = $people[$gift_selector];
    $gift_present = $gifts[$gift_selector];
    #                    ^missing s
    echo "It was then that the gods reached out and decided to give $gift_recipient the power of $gift_present to aid in this quest.<br/><br/>";
}
```

$heroname $friendname $wizardname $frogname need to be passed to the function or defined in the function unless they have been removed so you can display necessary code for us.

Comment: Just tried it your way and it fixed the gifts showing up, but even with passing the variables into the function, the names aren't showing up in the echo.

Comment: @HenryEdwardQuinnIV how are you calling the function?